# MYSQL AES Encryption/Decryption Failure

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

The final query should output the decrypted string 'test@test.com' from the updated 'email' field in the 'Login' table. However 'null' is returned.

AES encryption/decryption is failing somewhere.

```
SET @v1 = (SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('test@test.com', 'de1vuao6GkDMNyL7pV3p'));

UPDATE Login SET email = @v1 WHERE transactorID = 93779;

SET @v2 = SELECT email FROM Login where `transactorID` = 93779;

SELECT AES_DECRYPT(@v2,'de1vuao6GkDMNyL7pV3p');
```

Im using a mac running docker linux connecting via Sequel Pro Mac Gui

Comment: Is this the exact code you are running? You should get a syntax error for the "set @v2 = ..." - query (missing brackets, have to used the same way as you did it with @v1). If that's not, please provide the datatype of your email-column.

Comment: I have added the brackets but nothing gets returned. Datatype of email is VARBINARY.

Comment: Well, with brackets, the code itself should work fine, see the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8411fde0046f8cffd3135bfb653c684). You should check the intermediate steps (e.g print out the variables, check the result of the update/does the row exist, ...) and check for execution errors.